# Three.js + Blender: grouping objects to be loaded by SceneLoader

Tags: three.js

Is there a way to somehow group objects in Blender that works with SceneLoader?

I am using Blender to draw a scene with relatively large number of objects. Then I'm using SceneLoader to load that scene and dynamically pick out objects by name and dynamically re-position them. So far so good.

Now, I want to group some objects in Blender so that I can later find those objects by "group name". There are different ways of doing this in Blender, but I'm having hard time finding a way that works with SceneLoader.

I tried assigning objects into a group. Looking at the exported JSON file I see "groups" object property being exported, but SceneLoader completely ignores that property when it parses the JSON.

Going through the SceneLoader source code I noticed that it supports parent-child object relationship, so in Blender I tried [moving all objects that I want to group under a single parent](http://wiki.blender.org/index.php/Doc:2.6/Manual/Modeling/Objects/Groups_and_Parenting) but it looks like three.js exporter doesn't export parent-child relationships, but instead exports objects as a flat list.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Support for groups was [submitted into dev](https://github.com/mrdoob/three.js/commit/7c4624e0d11b8a92aa128613ddae3dc051c5dedc).